# Access environment variable inside global function - SwiftUI + CoreData

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I'm working on a list app, and I have some add/delete/edit/load functions for one specific data type, however I'd like to generalise those functions, so I can perform those same operations on any datatype, from within any view.

I've setup a global variable class:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class GlobalVariableClass: ObservableObject {
   @Published var itemObjects: [NSManagedObject] =  []
}
```

placed an instance of the class inside SceneDelegate

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

   var globalVariables = GlobalVariableClass()

   ...
```

passed the instance into contentView

```
let contentView = Home()
         .environmentObject(globalVariables)
         .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

Now when I declare `@EnvironmentObject var globalVariables: GlobalVariableClass` inside any *view*, I can access `itemObjects`, which stores all the items entered into a textfield.

That's great, but I'm trying to work with global functions, which aren't inside a view.

I'm declaring them inside a separate file at the global level so they have public access.

The exact problem is below inside the `do` block.

```
func loadItems() {

   guard let appDelegate =
      UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
         return
   }

   let managedContext =
      appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

   let fetchRequest =
      NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Item")

   do {
      GlobalVariableClass().itemObjects = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
   }   catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
   }
}
```

Accessing itemObjects with the `GlobalVariableClass().itemObjects` *results in nothing loading in my app.*

Though if I declare the load function inside the listItem view, declare the environment object `globalVariables`, then change it to

```
do {
      globalVariables.itemObjects = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
   }
```

then everything loads just fine.

Any suggestions on how I can access itemObjects from within global functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible approach is to use shared instance, like

```
class GlobalVariableClass: ObservableObject {
   static var shared = GlobalVariableClass()     // << here !!

   @Published var itemObjects: [NSManagedObject] =  []
}
```

so you can use it

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

   var globalVariables = GlobalVariableClass.shared
```

and

```
   do {
      let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

      // make sure to modify itemObjects always in main queue
      DispatchQueue.main.async {    // << must !!
         GlobalVariableClass.shared.itemObjects = results
      }
   }   catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
   }
```

Comment: You're a beautiful human being, that worked a treat!
Just wondering though, when you used GlobalVariableClass.shared, why didn't it require parentheses after GlobalVariableClass? First time seeing that.

Comment: @altec, because `shared` is static, so belongs to class, not to instance.