# Access and modify a @EnvironmentObject on global functions

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an `ObservableObject` declared on my main view (ContentView.swift).

```
final class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("stuff") public var notes: [NoteItem] = []
}
```

Then I declare it in the main entry of the app as (removed extra code not needed for this example):

```
@main struct The_NoteApp: App {

    private let dataModel = DataModel()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(self.dataModel)
        }
}
```

In the ContentView.swift, I can use it on the different views I declared there:

```
struct NoteView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var data: DataModel

    // more code follows...
}
```

Now, I have a collection of global functions saved on FileFunctions.swift, which essentially are functions that interact with files on disk. One of them is to load those files and their content into my app.

Now, I'm trying to use `@EnvironmentObject private var data: DataModel` in those functions so at loading time, I can populate the data model with the actual data from the files. And when I declare that either as a global declaration in FileFunctions.swift or inside each function separately, I get two behaviors.

With the first one I get an error:

> Global 'var' declaration requires an initializer expression or an explicitly stated getter`,

and

> Property wrappers are not yet supported in top-level code

I tried to initialize it in any way, but it goes nowhere. With the second one, adding them to each function, Xcode craps on me with a segfault. Even if I remove the `private` and try to declare it in different ways, I get nowhere.

I tried the solution in [Access environment variable inside global function - SwiftUI + CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61741970/access-environment-variable-inside-global-function-swiftui-coredata), but the more I move things around the worse it gets.

So, how would I access this `ObservableObject`, and how would I be able to modify it within global functions?

Below is an example of a global function and how it's being called.

In FileFunctions.swift I have:

```
func loadFiles() {    
    var text: String = ""
    var title: String = ""
    var date: Date
    
    do {
        let directoryURL = try resolveURL(for: "savedDirectory")
        if directoryURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
            let contents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: directoryURL,
                                                        includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
                                                        options: [.skipsHiddenFiles])
            for file in contents {
                text = readFile(filename: file.path)
                date = getModifiedDate(filename: file.absoluteURL)
                title = text.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.newlines).first!
                
                // I need to save this info to the DataModel here

            }
            directoryURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        } else {
            Alert(title: Text("Couldn't load notes"),
                  message: Text("Make sure the directory where the notes are stored is accessible."),
                  dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
        
        
    } catch let error as ResolveError {
        print("Resolve error:", error)
        return
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }
}
```

And I call this function from here:

```
@main struct The_NoteApp: App {

    private let dataModel = DataModel()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(self.dataModel)
                .onAppear {
                    loadFiles()
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: You should not have `loadFiles` anywhere in the views. You have a DataModel - let this do whatever is needed to load content. So, your `loadFile` _returns_ something! Also, in your `loadFiles` functions, don't show an Alert: either do a `fatalError` if this is a programmer error, or let it throw. The DataModel would call it, and it would be responsible to output an error state which you can render in your view. Also, don't name it `loadFiles` name it according _what_ it is loading - not _how_.

Comment: Thank you. A lot of "don't do it". I appreciate the feedback, but since I'm just beginning with Swift, code examples would be better in this case. And `loadFiles` does exactly what the name of the function says, it loads files.

Comment: If you move the `loadFiles` function into the view model, it gets a "context". You might also want to define a struct in your View Model which represents one Element of the things you get from "loadFiles". Let it name "FileInfo". This function may now return `[FileInfo]` - where FileInfo is a local struct in your ViewModel. Now, that naming (albite not perfect) makes a lot more sense now than when used in the free function, where it could mean everything and anything.  You could name your func now  just `func load() -> [FileInfo]`. ;)

Comment: If I move `loadFiles` into the view I need to write that function on each view where I need the files loaded ( it loads more than once to allow for file sync ). Hence my keeping all file related stuff that are reused in a separate place. You do make sense, I just don't know how to do this without rewriting a lot of the same code over and over. And for the `[FileInfo]` struct, I do have a struct for a single element, which I am using, however if you could provide an example of how to use this and how it makes the code better, it would be awesome.

Comment: But if I understood correctly, you would call `load()` and each file read would be returned into a `[FileInfo]` struct (which would be similar to the struct I already have). Now, if I do this right, each `[FileInfo]` would live in....?
What's the added benefit of this?

Comment: No, move `loadFiles` into the view model or your DataModel class. I will add an answer to illustrate this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the signature of the global functions to allow receiving the model:

```swift
func loadFiles(dataModel: DataModel) { ... }
```

This way, you have access to the model instance within the function, what's left to do is to pass it at the call site:

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(self.dataModel)
            .onAppear {
                loadFiles(dataModel: self.dataModel)
            }
```

You can do the same if the global functions calls originate from the views.

Comment: That works. I needed to change the call to `loadFiles(dataModel: self.dataModel)`. And not off to change the rest of the functions as well. Thank you.

Comment: @Aleph, yes, you only have to change the functions that need access to the `DataModel` instance.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this :

```
final class DataModel: ObservableObject {

    public static let shared = DataModel()

    @AppStorage("stuff") public var notes: [NoteItem] = []
}


@main struct The_NoteApp: App {

    private let dataModel = DataModel.shared
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(self.dataModel)
        }
}
```

now in your viewModel you can access it like this

```
class AnyClass {
   
   init (){
      print(DataModel.shared.notes)
   }
   // or 
   func printNotes(){
      print(DataModel.shared.notes)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The views are not the issue. The issues are on the global functions. How so I access the DataModel on those global functions?

Comment: In any class you can access it like this DataModel.shared.notes

Comment: Thank you, let me be maybe clearer in my question, how do I declare this on my file containing my global functions?

Comment: you don't need to declare this anywhere.

Comment: just use DataModel.shared Any where you want .

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, here a basic approach which makes some changes to the structure by defining dedicated "components" which have a certain role and which are decoupled as far as necessary.

I usually define a namespace for a "feature" where I put every "component" which is related to it. This offers a couple of advantages which you might recognise soon later:

```
enum FilesInfo {}
```

Using a "DataModel" or a "ViewModel" to separate your "Data" from the View
makes sense. A ViewModel - as opposed to DataModel - just obeys the rules from the MVVM pattern. A ViewModel should expose a "binding". I call this "ViewState", which *completely* describes what the view should render:

```
extension FilesInfo {

    enum ViewState {
         struct FileInfo {
             var date: Date 
             var title: String
         }
         
         case undefined
         case idle([FileInfo])

         init() { self = .undefined } // note that!
    }
}
```

Why ViewState is an enum?
Because you might want to represent also a loading state when your `load` function is asynchronous (almost always the case!) and an error state later. As you can see, you start with a state that's "undefined". You can name it also "zero" or "start", or however you like. It just means: "no data loaded yet".

A view model basically looks like this:

```
extension FilesInfo {
   
    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published private(set) var viewState: ViewState = .init()   

        ...
    }
}
```

Note, that there is a default initialiser for ViewState.

It also may have public functions where you can send "events" to it, which may originate in the view, or elsewhere:

```
extension FilesInfo.ViewModel {
    // gets the view model started.
    func load() -> Void {
        ...
    }

    // func someAction(with parameter: Param) -> Void
   
}
```

Here, the View Model implements `load()` - possibly in a similar fashion you implemented your `loadFiles`.

Almost always, a ViewModel operates (like an Actor) on an internal "State", which is not always the same as the ViewState. But your ViewState is a function of the State:

```
extension FilesInfo.ViewModel {
    private struct State {  
        ...
    }

    private func view(_ state: State) -> ViewState {
        //should be a pure function (only depend on state variable)
        // Here, you likely just transform the FilesInfo to 
        // something which is more appropriate to get rendered.

        // You call this function whenever the internal state
        // changes, and assign the result to the published 
        // property.
    }
   
}
```

Now you can define your FileInfosView:

```
extension FilesInfo {

    struct ContentView: View { 
       let state: ViewState
       let action: () -> Void // an "event" function
       let requireData: () -> Void // a "require data" event

       var body: some View { 
           ...
           .onAppear { 
              if case .undefined = state {
                  requireData()
              }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

When you look more closely on the ContentView, it has no knowledge from a ViewModel, neither from `loadFiles`. It only knows about the "ViewState" and it just renders this. It also has no knowledge when the view model is ready, or provides data. But it knows when it should render data but has none and then calls `requireData()`.

Note, it does not take a ViewModel as parameter. Those kind of setups are better done in some dedicated parent view:

```
extension FilesInfo {
    struct CoordinatorView: View {
        @ObservedObject viewModel: ViewModel 

        var body: some View {
            ContentView(
                state: viewModel.viewState, 
                action: {},
                requireData: viewModel.load
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Your "coordinator view" deals with separating ViewModel from your specific content view. This is not strictly necessary, but it increases decoupling and you can reuse your ContentView elsewhere with a different ViewModel.

Your CoordinatorView may also be responsible for creating the ViewModel and creating target views for navigation. This depends on what convention you establish.

IMHO, it may make sense, to restrict the access to environment variables to views with a certain role, because this creates a dependency from the view to the environment. We should avoid such coupling.

Also, I would consider mutating environment variables from within Views a "smell". Environment variables should be kind of a *configuration* which you setup in a certain place in your app (also called "CompositionRoot"). You may end up with an uncontrollable net of variables if you allow that everyone can change any environment variable at any time. When you have "ViewModels" in your environment, these of course get not "mutated" when they change their state - these are classes - for a reason.

Basically, that's it for a very basic but functional MVVM pattern.

Comment: Thank you, but I have no idea how to even approach understanding this. I get your not using env. variables, but everything else makes no sense to me. I'm seeing different `extension FilesInfo` doing different things. Are all these the same with different code? I wouldn't even know how to use these any way, I have 3 very simple and specific views, two lists and a text editor. Simple. I don't need other views, so I can't quite understand why I would make this into view. Besides, I still need to read files from disk, and this does not.

Comment: @Aleph The code above just has more structure. This helps to avoid making things complicated. Well, as mentioned, you still need to implement your `func loadFiles() -> [FileInfo]` function and assign the result your view state: `self.viewState = .idle(fileInfos)`. In your app, just create the CoordinatorView. done. Nothing fancy here. You sure can use the Environment, just be careful not to use it as some container for "global" variables. The "ContentView" is your "NoteView" - just a generic name, that describes the role rather the _what_. You can name it how you want.

Comment: Of course, the code above requires a minimal knowledge of Swift: enums with associated values, extensions, and functions which return a result, and basic SwiftUI.

Comment: I have minimal knowledge of Swift and SwiftUI. I'm a C programmer though, with some experience in Obj-C for macOS. Like I mentioned I'm a beginner in here.
So, the "lingo" is still not ingrained in me. A view uses a CoordinatorView vs a state, vs a collection of naming conventions that Apple use, make no sense to me yet. I can code alright, and in fact I have coded a working, usable app that I'm using everyday for mission critical stuff after 5 days of reading about swift, so, I can do this.

Comment: Yet, unless someone shows me that something **is**, I will not get it since Apple terminology makes no sense to me.

Comment: I posted the code I use. I load files from disk and save their content into a DataModel, which then populates and list and a texteditor component. In order to do this, I need to use environment stuff because it is fast and I can understand it. You said there is a better way, one that is "more swift-like", I believe you, you have more experience, but right now I don't see the benefit if doing this when I don't even understand why this is better, or how to add it to my already working app.

Comment: @Aleph one good point CouchDeveloper makes, is to convert `loadFiles` from a global function to a member function. So basically instead of having `loadFiles(dataModel: self.dataModel)`, you'd be writing `self.dataModel.loadFiles()`, which gets you to a more cohesive design. But this works only if `loadFiles` doesn't populate stuff on other objects/models.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Let me see how I can do this. Thanks!